# How virtual particles affect the moving of electrons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, atoms

We know that empty space is not really empty, but
there are virtual particle pairs of electrons and positrons that are constantly generated and annihilated.

We also know that in an atom, there is empty space for the most part. Have we ever wondered how these virtual particles affect the moving of an electron? What if the moving of an electron is due that it pairs with the virtual positron created and the other electron created is new?

Comment: Check this out: https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.6165

Comment: The paper tries to explain the speed of light in terms of continuously appearing and disappearing fermion pairs. This in turn gives rise to the notion of finite electrical and magnetic permeability, and hence its effect on movement of electron.